# Convert excel formula to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, formula

Hi I have a table in excel which has a formula with it. I need this formula to be in SQL form. I have tried this:

`SELECT IIF (C2 = "L",IIF(B2 < A4,B4,B2),A4)`

but i need to convert the cell to a SQL selection

Here is a link to the table:

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFJ4l.png)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS flavor you are using (it shouldn't be too important for a question like this, but better to have all info). Does the contents of the excel document now exist in a table on your server? What is your desired output? SQL doesn't use "formulas", it uses queries against a table to return a specific set of data. A proper SQL query would look like this: `SELECT [column_list] FROM [table_name] WHERE [condition];` for example: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 > 4;`

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid in T-SQL, with single quotes:

```
-- the data
DECLARE @items TABLE
(
 A2 char(3),
 A4 int,
 B2 int,
 B4 int,
 C2 char(1)
);

INSERT INTO @items VALUES
('Foo', 0, 1, 2, 'R'),
('Bar', 0, 1, 2, 'L'),
('Foo', 4, 3, 2, 'L');

-- the formula
SELECT *, IIF (C2 = 'L', IIF(B2 < A4, 'B4', 'B2'), 'A4') AS RESULT, IIF (C2 = 'L', IIF(B2 < A4, B4, B2), A4) AS FORMULA FROM @items;
```

returns:

```
A2  A4 B2 B4 C2  RESULT FORMULA
--- -- -- -- --  ------ -------
Foo 0  1  2  R   A4     0
Bar 0  1  2  L   B2     1
Foo 4  3  2  L   B4     2
```